# How to find out what operators rigify is using when running IKFK snap?

Tags: python, rigify

I am trying to understand what rigify is doing under the hood. specifically when running the FK>IK commands.
How can I discover what python operators are called when I press those buttons ?
the info Editor doesn't log anything for IKFK snapping, nor does the console, and I can't seem to find any documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the whole Rigify add-on code in

`C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.4\3.4\scripts\addons\rigify\`

I have little to do with rigging, but looking at the code it seems like there aren't so many operators. From the first shallow look it seems it relies more on the rigs for IK>FK, constraints maybe?.. Anyway, all the code is there, you can have a look at how it works exactly.